# Convert VB set/get function to c# function

Tags: c#, vb.net, activex

I'm trying to convert following vb set/get function to c#. It is used through an ActiveX page like :

```
Item.CtxString(document.getElementById("setvar").value+"1")=document.getElementById("setval").value;
```

or :

```
 Item.CtxString("var1") = "var";
```

The following code is used in VB.NET :

```
Public Property CtxString(ByVal strItemType As String) As String
        Get
            Try
                Return myContext.ContextString(strItemType)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ""
            End Try
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Try
                myContext.ContextString(strItemType) = value
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Set
    End Property

 Public Sub SetCtxString(ByVal strItemType As String, ByVal value As String)
        Try
            myContext.ContextString(strItemType) = value
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I'm trying to convert this from VB to C#, with following function :

```
   public string CtxString
    {
        get
        {
            return ctxString;

        }
        set
        {
            ctxString = value;
        }
    }

public void SetCtxString(string value)
{
    this.ctxString = value;
}
```

ContextString is a function used in c++, which needs to be converted to c# aswell..

```
STDMETHODIMP CContextATL::get_ContextString(BSTR strItemType, BSTR *pVal)
{
    try
    {
        _bstr_t strItem(strItemType, true);
        _bstr_t strTemp;
        char szBuffer[2048] = {0};

        CContextItem *pItem = _Module.GetContextItemFromEnvironment(m_strEnv, (char *)strItem);
        if(pItem != NULL)
        {
            strTemp = pItem->GetContextStringValue().c_str();
            *pVal = ::SysAllocString(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(strTemp)); 
            sprintf( szBuffer, "ContextString Key = '%s' Value = '%s' read by Client %s with name = %s in Environment %s\r\n", (char *)strItem, (char *)strTemp, m_strId.c_str(), m_strClientName.c_str(), m_strEnv.c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf( szBuffer, "ContextString Key = '%s' not found while reading by Client %s with name = %s in Environment %s\r\n", (char *)strItem, m_strId.c_str(), m_strClientName.c_str(), m_strEnv.c_str());
        }
        _Module.WriteDebugString(szBuffer);
    }
    catch(_com_error & e)
    {
        ATLTRACE("CContextATL::get_ContextString exception : %s\n", e.ErrorMessage());
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Anyone who could help me out to convert the following function from VB.NET to c#?

Comment: whats wrong with what you have? other than you didnt put in the try portions?

Comment: Seems ok to me too, you can add try catch also

Comment: No flaws, you just add try-catch.

Comment: I'm able to use : Item.CtxString = "test"; but not Item.CtxString("value") = "test"; why is that?

Comment: I want to use this to set key value pairs as example

Answer (score 0):

The VB property is a "parameterized property" - this is not available in C#, so you would convert this to 2 separate methods:

```
public string get_CtxString(string strItemType)
{
    try
    {
        return myContext.ContextString(strItemType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
public void set_CtxString(string strItemType, string value)
{
    try
    {
        myContext.ContextString(strItemType) = value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Your original 'set' method is now redundant:

```
public void SetCtxString(string strItemType, string value)
{
    try
    {
        myContext.ContextString(strItemType) = value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? C# can overload bracket operator.

I have no idea what's `ContextString` is, however, if `ContextString` is a `Dictionary` or the type uses brackets to get value, you can do it like this:

```
public string this[string strItemType]
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return myContext.ContextString[strItemType];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            myContext.ContextString[strItemType] = value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TomD Would you please tell me what the `ContextString`is?